# cout prints "-0" instead of "0"

Tags: c++, floating-point

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double u = 0;
    double w = -u;
    cout << w << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why does this great piece of code output `-0` and not `0`, as one would expect?

Comment: a bit more context would be appreciated (like the compiler used for a start)

Comment: Great C++ code cannot have `using namespace std;`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The IEEE 754 standard for floating-point numbers has the sign bit separate from the mantissa, which allows for zero to be negative.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) should be able to help explain this.

Answer (score 2):

In IEEE floating point `0` and `-0` are both distinct values, from [here](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html) under "Special Values":

> Note that -0 and +0 are distinct
>   values, though they both compare as
>   equal.

Answer (score 2):

The IEEE 754 standard for floating point arithmetic makes a distinction between `+0` and `-0`, this can be used when dealing with very small numbers rounded to zero where the sign still has an importance.

Answer (score 1):

Because "negative zero" is a valid number!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%88%920_(number)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point.  Note that there is a sign bit, even if the value is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Because a double can indeed have values -0, +0, -infinity, +infinity and NaN, which can be a result of various interesting expressions, like 0/0.

Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%88%920_(number)) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Because your expectations are wrong.

IEEE requires that positive and negative zero be represented seperately.

That is what you're seeing here.