# Weird sign issue when computing sine or cosine

Tags: c++, floating-point, decimal, precision, sign

I'm trying to write a small program that calculates the sine and cosine of an angle that the user provides in degrees, with 6 decimal places of precision.

It goes like this:

Input (angle)

```
90
```

Output (sine  cosine)

```
1.000000 0.000000
```

But I have an issue with some of them, for instance, when user inputs **-850**, the program returns:

```
-1.000000 -0.000000
```

Notice the **-0.000000**, is there a clean way to avoid this? It must be really simple but I'm missing it.

BTW, by a clean way I mean cleaner than something like

```
if(angle > -0.000001)
{
        angle = 0.000000;
}
```

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        float angle;

        while(1)
        {
                cin >> angle;
                if(cin.eof())
                {
                        return 0;
                }
                angle = angle*M_PI/180.0;
                cout << fixed << setprecision(6) << sin(angle) << " " << cos(angle) << endl;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Are you still actively looking for an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answer in this case is to print the numbers to a string and then examine the string. If the string is the literal constant -0.000000 then replace it with 0.000000.

This may seem like a hack but it is actually the most stable solution. You could try clamping the input value as suggested in the solution by comparing it against -0.000001 but that doesn't necessarily tell you whether -0.000000 would have been printed. If the printing code rounds to nearest then -0.0000009 will print as -0.000001, but the check will cause it to print as zero, which is arguably a bug.

Just do the string check and move on. It is the only solution that is guaranteed to be exactly correct. Or, if you don't mind perhaps having slightly too few 0.000000 results, use the comparison against -0.000001.

Or, just leave the code alone. The -0.000000 actually gives additional information - it's not really a bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

[What every programmer should know about floating point](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

You could do:

```
if (angle == -0.0) { angle = 0.0 }
```

I haven't been about to find a way to tell iostream not to print the minus sign on negative zero.

Comment: I know about rounding errors, I'm not asking for an explanation, I'm asking for a solution. Maybe I should've clarified that point...

Comment: It's not just rounding error, IEEE floating point really has a negative zero. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73686/cout-prints-0-instead-of-0.

Comment: This answer is not actually correct. It is very likely that the actual result is something like -0.000000000047. When it is formatted for display with six digits of precision it is printed as -0.000000. Your check will not alter this.